# what does "runaway argument" after \includegraphics mean?

Tags: includegraphics, suftesi

code is

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{figures/112.jpg}

\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{figures/133}
```

in a suftesi document. No error, if the two includegraphics are commented out; they produce the error and no output - but I cannot see where a `}` is missing?
without the `[scale..]` or `[width=...]` argument, some part of the jpg file appear in the output pdf.

```
[5] [6]
Runaway argument?
width=0.5\paperwidth ]{figures/112.jpg} 
./4210action.tex:52: Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.52 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get this error if you load graphics instead of graphicx (with x)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics} %<-- change to graphicx
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick. I had no \usepackage{graphics} in my code, obviously I got it indirectly from \documentclass{suftesi}. I have added \usepackage{graphicx} and the figures appear as intended.

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting the `.aux` file did solve a similar error, when `graphicx` was already included. Credit goes to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525375/runaway-argument-error-from-tex) answer.

Nevertheless, I found this question first while searching a solution.